# Haskell conversion of ordered list into a balanced tree ~ Code Explanation

Tags: haskell

I have the following exercise:

Define the function list2tree which converts a given ordered list into a balanced tree – the height of the right and the left subtree for any node of this tree can differ at most by 1.

Can anyone explain this code and how does it work ? Also how can i test the tree in console ?

> Solution:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a
          | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
          | Null

list2tree [] = Null
list2tree [x] = Leaf x
list2tree list = Node x (list2tree ltx) (list2tree gtx)
                 where 
                 m = length list `div` 2
                 x = list !! m
                 ltx = take m list
                 gtx = drop (m+1) list
```

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about the code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

What this function does is taking the middle element in the list, putting it as the node and then recursing for every half of the list. `m` is the position of the middle element, `ltx` (which I believe mean "lower than x") are all the element lower, than `x` and `gtx` are all the elements higher than x.

Answer (score 2):

In order to test in GHCI, make `Tree` an instance of `Show`:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a
          | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
          | Null
          deriving (Show)
```

Start GHCI from the command line, and load the file that contains `Tree` and `list2tree`. I called it `44520938.hs`:

```
Prelude> :load 44520938.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Answer           ( 44520938.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Answer.
```

Now you can call the function with various input lists to test:

```
*Answer> list2tree []
Null
*Answer> list2tree [1]
Leaf 1
*Answer> list2tree [1, 2]
Node 2 (Leaf 1) Null
*Answer> list2tree [1, 2, 3]
Node 2 (Leaf 1) (Leaf 3)
```

Comment: after where, i can't understand how this code works, i need to remember this exercise for my test. But it is important to understand how it works